# Ruby code written in TextEdit won't run

Tags: ruby, editor, double-quotes

I'm using a Mac with OSX 10.10.1
I made a folder called `myruby`, then saved a file with TextEdit, called `first.rb`. The file says

```
puts "Hello World"
```

In Terminal I typed `cd myruby`. I used `ls` to ensure the file is there.
When I type `ruby first.rb` I get this message:

```
first.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant World” (NameError)"
```

What am I doing wrong? Clearly the file exists, and Terminal goes as far as opening it, but then it can't run it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show a minimal amount of research effort.

Comment: I did search the forum, and I found some related questions, but it seems like all of them were solved by something else, like incorrect capitalization or not being in the right file. I haven't found anything with this error message yet, where Terminal has found the file but can't run it.

Comment: the error explains what went wrong; `unitialized constant World" (NameError)`. You're trying to call a value without the corresponding symbol having been initialized first. This is explained in depth and with examples in [one of the first results on Google](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NameError.html).

Comment: @Jules I think you're being harsh.  The "smart" (really not-so-smart) quote is a tricky little thing that is difficult to notice.

Comment: BTW, you _are_ running `first.rb`. That [`NameError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/NameError.html) is a Ruby exception, not a Terminal / shell error.

Answer (score 7):

Look very closely at the error message:

```
first.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant World” (NameError)
```

The uninitialized constant it's complaining about is named `World”`.

I'm guessing that your file doesn't say this:

```
puts "Hello World"
```

I'm guessing that it says this:

```
puts “Hello World”
```

Spot the difference? `“` and `”` aren't the same as `"`.

The immediate solution is to turn off Smart Quotes (and other automatic text transformations) in TextEdit. The long-term solution is to use something other than TextEdit; it's not suitable for programming. Try something like SublimeText or Atom, which are designed for programming, instead.

Comment: Great recommendations. Step 1 in learning programming is to understand every single character matters and "close enough" is not going to cut it.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Sorry for the very basic question, I'm very very new to all of this, just figuring everything out!

Comment: No worries, it's pretty tricky the first time you run into it and pretty much impossible to search for!